# redirect to an url returned in JSON arrays response from API in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to redirect to an url that i have received in JSON from API.

```
<?php


    include('yandex/lib/autoload.php');
    use YandexCheckout\Client;

    $client = new Client();
    //$client->setAuth('', 'live_icDc3oRTP8kU3QWnyeeSsVE2-jeTHR0ZegtwGGrCqRw');
    $client->setAuth('test', 'test_wOh1a3SNgOTaGuYNg5FzOEyDo11yg2KY9GqEJquyg3s');
    $payment = $client->createPayment(
        array(
            'amount' => array(
                'value' => 10.0,
                'currency' => 'RUB',
            ),
            'confirmation' => array(
                'type' => 'redirect',
                'return_url' => 'https://www.test.com/response.php',
            ),
            'capture' => true,
            'description' => 'Order No. 1',
        ),
        uniqid('', true)
    );

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$paymentarray = json_encode($payment);

print_r($paymentarray);



?>
```

here is the json print i have in browser.

```
{
    "id": "258bf08a-000f-5000-a000-1882b803aeac",
    "status": "pending",
    "paid": false,
    "amount": {
        "value": "10.00",
        "currency": "RUB"
    },
    "confirmation": {
        "type": "redirect",
        "confirmation_url": "https://money.yandex.ru/api-pages/v2/payment-confirm/epl?orderId=258bf08a-000f-5000-a000-1882b803aea"
    },
    "created_at": "2019-12-18T08:01:14.762Z",
    "description": "Order No. 1",
    "metadata": {},
    "recipient": {
        "account_id": "some",
        "gateway_id": "some"
    },
    "refundable": false,
    "test": true
}
```

i need to redirect it to the url, confirmation_url object received in json array using php.
i have tried following code to get data but its blank.

```
$paymentdata = json_decode($paymentarray, true);
echo $paymentdata['confirmation']['confirmation_url'];
echo $paymentdata['id'];
```

Comment: cannot reproduce, your code works fine - [demo](https://3v4l.org/B9v00)

Comment: I checked your code work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = json_decode($paymentarray,true);

$url = $data['confirmation']['confirmation_url'];
header("location:".$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the json response posted, json_decode function returns an object, not an array. Try:

```
echo $paymentdata->confirmation->confirmation_url;
```

Comment: `json_decode(..., true)` returns an associative array